# if statement based on subset of indexes - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list containing a subset of indexes values from my dataframe. I want to return a value (x) if the dataframe index is within that list and nothing ('') elsewhere. I tried the expression below without result.

```
df.loc[indexList]['Col'] = 'x'
```

Could you tell me how to make it work and why the example above didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get a warning?  Sometimes Pandas will print a SettingWithCopyWarning when you make this mistake.

This code is broken:

```
df.loc[indexList]['Col'] = 'x'
```

Because `df.loc[indexList]` returns a copy, which you then modify and discard.

Instead, try:

```
df.loc[indexList, 'Col'] = 'x'
```

Then you will not be "getting" but rather "setting" the result of the indexList subset, which avoids copying the data.

Comment: Your 1st option works perfectly. Second one only works if 'Col' is already defined and it triggers a warning. Thanks !

Comment: @dominic111: You're welcome--I removed the second option, I see that it won't work for you now.